# SkipValidation is not working in Jdeveloper 12c properly

Tags: validation, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have developed an employee data setup form and it has all mandatory validations. So whenever I will run that page if I will try to switch to another tab or page or click on logout then it will always show these all errors.

I have found that on the page definition xml file, in the structure, there is SkipValidation, which need to be set as true. So it will skip all these validations on navigation.

But after setting it as true. It's not avoiding these validations. 
So Please suggest me some way to avoid it.

Comment: You can set immediate property to "true" on the button. This will skip the validation . Or if you are on 12c you can try `af:target`

Comment: see this blog post for how to do what you want:http://www.slideshare.net/stevendavelaar/18-invaluable-lessons-about-adfjsf-interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**skipValidation** will not work if you have *required* set to true on the component as those validations fire on the client side.  It's not a bug, the logout button should just have immediate=true set. As why would you ever want to submit the values in the form on logout.

Also, skipValidation would still validate the values at commit time, it just defers the model validation to later stage.